# Getting VLOOKUP() to default to closest date

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have two tables shown in the link [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0jfd.jpg).  I am trying to calculate columns `J` and `K` in the second table based on the row that has the closest date match in the first table.  To give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do, I have this formula for column `J`:

`=F3-VLOOKUP(C3,'Agency Comps2'!B:G, 5, TRUE)`

And this formula for column `K`:

`=H3-VLOOKUP(C3,'Agency Comps2'!B:G,5,TRUE)`

Where `Agency Comps2` is the name of the first sheet that I'm trying to look up values in.

As you can see, the values I'm getting are either wrong, or `#N/A`.  I have been trying to find a way to make `VLOOKUP()` default to the closest date, but I can't seem to do so.  Can anyone help me get the values I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRUE as the last parameter in Vlookup only works if the lookup range is sorted ascending.

From the screenshot it looks as if the dates may not be real dates. The green warning triangles raise some concerns.

Make sure that the dates are real dates, then the formula will work.